# Mysql search , express response issue

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, regex, express

How write a code which will bring me items from MYSQL-DB which will match some of the letters with request? For example I write to the end of link "samsung" but the name of item is "samsung s9, s8 etc...". How to get all of items? This is my code which is note work.

```
app.get('/models/:name', (req, res, next)=>{
const connection = getConnection();
const queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE name=?'

const modelName = req.params.name;

connection.query( queryStr, [modelName], (err, rows, fields)=>{
    if (err){
        res.send('<h1>500 bad request</h1> Error! Sorry for error, we are working on it!');
        res.sendStatus(500);
       return;
        //throw err;
    }
    console.log('Ready');
    res.json(rows);
})
// res.end();
```

})

Comment: you can use wildcard character `%` here like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE name like "%samsung%"`

Comment: Thank you for answering! I will try.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: "Doesn't work"?  Crashes?  Returns no rows?  Returns the wrong rows?  Did you change from `=` to `LIKE`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE products`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use wildcard character % like `'SELECT * FROM products WHERE name=%anyMobileName%'`

IMO Instead of creating MYSQL query from your own and executing these use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) ORM

Comment: Thank you for answering. The code above doesn't work. I will try sequelize. Thank you.